# Maximize a function with an interpolating function as a constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization, interpolation

Consider the following interpolating function, `i`, which is constructed using the data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5frv0czd9yuz939/data.csv?dl=0).

```
data = Import["data.csv"];
i = Interpolation[data]
```

Now, I want to find the values of `x` (0, 1.8)  and `y` (0, 1.8) where `y'[x]` is maximized subject to the following condition,

```
cond = 1.8 - 10^6 i[x, y] == y;
```

Using `FindRoot`, we can get an idea of the relation between `y` and `x`:

```
y0[x_]:= y/.FindRoot[cond,{y,x}];
```

It can be clearly seen that around `x = 0.7`, the slope is the highest. This value is what I want.

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```
yd[x_, y_] := -10^6(i[x + 0.01, y] - i[x, y])/0.01 ; (*I am using forward difference*)
NMaximize[{Abs[yd[x, y]], cond, 0 <= x <= 1.8, 0 <= y <= 1.8}, {x, y}]
```

> NMaximize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {}.
>
> {-∞, {x-> Indeterminate, y-> Indeterminate}}

But clearly from the above plot it can be seen that there are points which satisfy the condition.
I am not able to understand why it throws this warning. 
Can anyone point me out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post `data.csv` in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: @J.M. I tried initially with `pastebin` but it says the data exceeds 512KB, so I resorted to `dropbox`. If there is any other viable option, I would gladly put it there.